# enable log through config file

Tags: magento-1.8, logging

Is it possible to enable system/exception logging in Magento through `local.xml`, instead of doing it by DB saved settings?

Or at least via code (but changing the setting only for one particular execution, without changing the configuration in the DB)?

What I'm after is to be able to have a different configuration for dev/production, one with log enable and the other without logging). And even if I'm not using the same DBs, every time we download the production DB to continue testing we have to reset settings.

Comment: where you need? Default log for  exception in exception.log.

Comment: The default logs. To enable the same behavior as in going to settings (System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings ) and enable logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable logging programmatically, you can do:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('dev/log/active',true);
```

To disable it:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('dev/log/active',false);
```

Comment: While it works, it would be nice to be able to alter the settings only temporarily. An equivalent to WP_DEBUG=true, or php's display_errors()...

Comment: via local.xml would be the perfect place. I thought it would be doable...

Comment: @yivi unfortunately I'm not aware of any temporary way of doing it